# Magento SELECT via ORM

Tags: php, mysql, magento, orm

I would like to know how can I do a SELECT from a Magento core table but not using pure SQL but using collections.

Currently, inside a class that extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract, on a given function I have the following code:

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton("core/resource");

$tableName_SalesQuoteItem = $resource->getTableName("sales/quote_item");

$readConnection = $resource->getConnection("core_read");

$sqlInstruction = "SELECT item_id FROM {$tableName_SalesQuoteItem} WHERE sku = :sku AND quote_id = :quote_id;";

$binds = array("sku" => $itemSku, "quote_id" => $quoteID);

$result = $readConnection->query($sqlInstruction, $binds);

if($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $currentItemID = $row["item_id"];
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you specify which collection you're attempting to load? Which table are you attempting to get the rows out of ( with the children table values available )?

Comment: Hey Vladimir, the table I'm trying to get the data from is sales_flat_quote_item. Based on the Magento docs, you can get the table name like this: 

$tableName_SalesQuoteItem = $resource->getTableName("sales/quote_item");

So far I have been able to execute a straight sql but not use a Magento Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be is that you're trying to load the header table `'sales/quote'` and call items on it, when the items are stored in the sub-table `sales/quote_item`

Here's a functional prototype:

```
<?php
    require_once( 'app/Mage.php' );

    umask(0);
    Mage::app('default');

    $sCustomerId = 1;
    $oQuotes = Mage::getModel( 'sales/quote' )->getCollection();
    $oQuotes->addFieldToFilter( 'customer_id', $sCustomerId );
    foreach( $oQuotes as $oQuote )
    {
        var_dump( $oQuote->getId() );
        var_dump( $oQuote->getData( 'customer_email' ) );
        var_dump( $oQuote->getData( 'customer_id' ) );

        $oItems = Mage::getModel( 'sales/quote_item' )
            ->getCollection()
            ->setQuote( $oQuote );
        foreach( $oItems as $oItem )
        {
            var_dump( $oItem->getData( 'sku' ) );
            var_dump( $oItem->getData( 'name' ) );
            var_dump( $oItem->getData( 'description' ) );
            var_dump( $oItem->getData( 'price' ) );
        }
    }
    $iCountQuotes = $oQuotes->count();
    var_dump( $iCountQuotes );
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir, your code works like a charm. I will update a github gist with the final code I used soon.

Comment: Here is my final code:

https://gist.github.com/jpruiz114/30371d43efc85c6fb1a1

Thanks again for your help @Vladimir.

Comment: This was my previous version:

https://gist.github.com/jpruiz114/b1676b513042005224be

Answer (score 0):

From your question it appears that you are looking for an ORM way to achieve the same thing you are doing with your query.

Here you go:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku',$itemSku);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('quote_id',$quoteID);

if($collection->count())
{
                //Add your code here
                $firstItem = $collection->getFirstItem();
                print_r($firstItem);

}
```

Read more about Magento ORM basics [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics)

You could alternatively try **addFieldToFilter** if **addAttributeToFilter** doesn't work.

Comment: Hey Harit, but some reason the line of the $collection->count is triggering an error. The weirdest thing is that I can not get the detail on a try catch block.

Comment: I have to say that I tried both using addFieldToFilter and addAttributeToFilter.

Comment: Alternatively try getSize() function instead of count()